# High power factor but maximum current at resonance in series RLC circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, ac, resonance, power-factor-correction

In a series RLC circuit, at resonance, the power factor is unity but the current is high. But since in high power factor the current drawn is low, then isn't this a paradox? High current is undesirable, so we have high power factor, but the current is maximum at resonance frequency in a series RLC circuit. Can any one explain?

Comment: Curiousgurl, are we done with this now or is there something that you still need to know.

Comment: Thank you. Yes i understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *In a series RLC circuit, at resonance, the power factor is unity but
> the current is high.*

Correct but talking about power factor here might be irrelevant.

> *But since in high power factor the current drawn is low, then isn't
> this a paradox?*

Power factor correction circuits use **parallel resonance** to achieve power factors approaching unity and thus, they (parallel PF correction circuits) minimize the current drawn. **Series resonance** isn't used in PF correction circuits.